# Solving all possible values for a functional composition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined over the real number set $\Bbb R$ as follows:
$$
g(x)=1 - x + x^2 \\
f(x) = ax + b
$$
If $g ◦ f(x) = 16x^2 - 12x + 3$,
determine all the possible values of $a$ and $b$.

I have no idea where to even start with this, I've attempted using inverse functions, plotting and expanding out the composition hoping for an equation to be solved, but no luck, just more arbitrary values.

Comment: What does $g\circ f$ look like?  Compare coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(g\circ f)(x) = 1-f(x) + [f(x)]^2 = 1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2 = 16x^2-12x+3$$

Expand the left-hand side, and match coefficients. You'll have three equations in two unknowns (where the unknowns are $a$, $b$).

Comment: Much appreciated! Had something very similar on my whiteboard, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: You're welcome!